# conversion of pushdown automata

Tags: theory, computation

what will be the pushdown automata for the language
L = { wxw^r | w is in (0+1)* and x is either 0 or 1
I also want to know the transitions  if we pass string 001000100
please help I am stick because the length of x is 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For a context free grammar, how do i convert it to an equivalent push down automaton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161722/for-a-context-free-grammar-how-do-i-convert-it-to-an-equivalent-push-down-autom)

Comment: For it to be a good question, please include what you have tried to solve it and why that did not work. In general, you should also see if similar questions like these have been asked already.